# How to use sapply to apply function to vector_a[i] returning value from vector_b[i]

Tags: r, sapply

I want to apply a function to each value of dataframe$column1 returning a vector of the same length. The output should contain the value from dataframe$column2 (of the same row) if a condition apply. In (pseudo)code

```
function <- "If (value of dataframe$column1[i] is something) {return(dataframe$column1[i])} else {return(dataframe$column2[i])}  

output_vector <- sapply(dataframe$column1, function, dataframe$column2)
```

Does sapply remember the index of the vector when applying a function so to return a value from a different vector but with the same index?

Comment: Consider providing an example data set and the expected answer.  That would help me.  Although perhaps the question is clear enough to others.

Comment: sapply does not pass the index to your function.  As Marius points out, this is what ifelse is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what `ifelse()` does:

```
df = data.frame(col1=1:10, col2=21:30)
output_vector = ifelse(df$col1 > 5, df$col1, df$col2)
```

Comment: @CptNemo if you really, really want to use a member of the `apply` family of functions you could embed the `ifelse` statement like this... ...although doing so seems unnecessary in this case: `df$col3 <- apply(df, 1, function(i) ifelse(i[1] > 5 , i[1], i[2]))`